# How to bind a NSMutableArray to several NSTextFields

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I am new to cocoa bindings and objective c.
I am working on a UI screen which has got several NSTextFields in a NSWindowController.

My UI Window controller gets a array of dictionary as input to these text Field.

Without using IBOutlets, how can I fetch values from the array and display in a textField

Comment: You can't do that unless you use a table view to populate the table from the array

Comment: Why do you not want to use IBOutlets?

Comment: Which values do you want to use? Do you want all values from the same element? Are the text fields editable?

Comment: You can't bind to a keypath on the array, because you need to provide a parameter-- the object index in the array.  Unless you want `firstObject` or `lastObject`. So, if you have a limited number of objects, you could extend NSArray with a category and create `secondObject` `thirdObject` etc.  And since you say you have nested dictionaries, you'll likely have to create custom parameterless getter methods to put in the keypath there, too.  And extending NSArray with a category can slow everything down...

Comment: Cocoa also provides an NSDictionaryController that does for dictionaries exactly what NSArrayController does for arrays. There's a sample project at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/DictionaryController/Introduction/Intro.html. Download the project and run it; if it looks like it's doing what you want it to do, you should work your way through the code.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers
TextFields are not editable
Textfields in my UI Screen gets populated based on the selection of table rows from the previous screen
I wrote a program which provide inputs to my UI screen (NSWindowController) a array consisted of selected row items as dictionary.  
       So its array of dictionaries.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to bind each textfields in my UI screen to arrayController (consisting of array) and populate textfields from the content to the array binded based on the key in the dictionary which is in a array.

Comment: You can't bind NSTextField to a row in an array controller. Should the contents of the textfields automatically change when the data or selection in the first tableview changes? Is the number of textfields fixed? Can't you use NSTableView or NSOulineView?